# Different values of class member in constructor and out of it

Tags: c++

That would be one of those super-simple-questions but I really can't remind myself why is that going on. So: I have a simple constructor in which I initialize some variables, int in this example, and I also have a method that helps me to print this int out. But what is wrong is in constructor I have right value of my int, but outside I get some random stuff. Why is that happening and how to prevent it?

Here's player.cpp:

```
#include "player.h"
#include <iostream>

player::player()
{
    int position = 1;
}

void player::get_pos()
{
    std::cout << "You position is: " << this->position << std::endl;
}
```

and player.h

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H


class player
{
    int position;
public:
    player();
    void get_pos();
};

#endif // PLAYER_H
```

I have also tried it without `this->position` but it is not working anyway. This seems accurate to me, because I want to know the position of THIS object.

Answer (score 1):

You constructor:

```
player::player()
{
    int position = 1;
}
```

Is declaring a local variable called `position` and setting that rather than setting the class member as expected.

try:

```
player::player()
{
    position = 1;
}
```

Comment: OMG.. that is why I hate stoping my learning. Rookie mistake, as always. Thank you ;)